# Export TikZ as PDF and size

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, animations, animate

I am trying to create an animation where two balls are created and there radii continously increase. I therefore create a variety of pdfs and use `\animategraphics` in order to create the animation.

However I have trouble with the output of the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\foreach \r in {0.1,0.5}{
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rr}{0.05}

\coordinate (1) at (-1.04,0.65);
\coordinate (2) at (2.2,1.18);

\draw[gray,fill=blue] (1) circle (\r);
\draw[gray,fill=blue] (2) circle (\r);
\draw[black,fill=red] (1) circle (\rr);
\draw[black,fill=red] (2) circle (\rr);

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

This creates two pdfs. But if you compare the first graphic with the second one you notice that the midpoints are shifted. Hence in the animation also the midpoints seem to be moving. However I only want to blow up the balls around those points.

Does anyone know a solution to my problem?

**Edit:**
I solved it by placing two transparent nodes at the lower-left and upper-right corner as suggested in the first comment (which was deleted for some reason).

Comment: Place `\noindent` after `\begin{document}`. Place `%` character after the `foreach`, after `\centering`, and after `\end{tikzpicture}` lines and try again

Comment: @percusse thx for your response. But it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames used in `\animategraphics` must have the same physical dimensions.

Therefore, add a common boundingbox by means of

> ```
> \useasboundingbox (...) rectangle (...);
> ```

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{external} 
%\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\foreach \r in {0.1,0.5}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rr}{0.05}

\coordinate (1) at (-1.04,0.65);
\coordinate (2) at (2.2,1.18);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\useasboundingbox ([shift={(-0.51,-0.51)}] 1) rectangle ([shift={(0.51,0.51)}] 2);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\draw[gray,fill=blue] (1) circle (\r);
\draw[gray,fill=blue] (2) circle (\r);
\draw[black,fill=red] (1) circle (\rr);
\draw[black,fill=red] (2) circle (\rr);

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

---

**Example using `animateinline` environment:**

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[loop,autoplay]{12}
  \multiframe{41}{r=0.1+0.01}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rr}{0.05}

    \coordinate (1) at (-1.04,0.65);
    \coordinate (2) at (2.2,1.18);
    \useasboundingbox ([shift={(-0.51,-0.51)}] 1) rectangle ([shift={(0.51,0.51)}] 2);

    \draw[gray,fill=blue] (1) circle (\r);
    \draw[gray,fill=blue] (2) circle (\r);
    \draw[black,fill=red] (1) circle (\rr);
    \draw[black,fill=red] (2) circle (\rr);

    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thx for your answer. It works fine now.